# Decimal to binary using sign, exponent, magnitude

Tags: assembly, binary, operating-system

I have an operating systems final later today and i'm looking over my past exams. Anyways long story short I got it wrong, this isn't a HW problem I'm just unsure how to do it.

"Suppose we use 32 bits to represent a real number, with 1 bit for the sign of the number, 7 bits for the exponent, and 24 bits for the magnitude. Show the bit pattern for the number 0.5"

The way i did it on the exam was to multiply the number by 2, keep the first digit before the decimal point and repeat the process with the remainder if it's remainder is not a 0, otherwise we are done.

0.5 * 2 =1.0

0 * 2 =x

answer 1

but this isn't correct, can anyone help me with the process? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming [a bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias) of 63 on the exponent and an implicit leading 1 on the mantissa, I'd conclude the following bit pattern:

`0 0111110 000000000000000000000000`  (== `0x3E000000`)

I.e.

`+(1 + 0) * power(2, 62-63)`

== `+1 * power(2, -1)`

== `+1 * 0.5` == `+0.5`

([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format))

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are explaining, could you go into more details/explaining?

Comment: You didn't fully specify the encoding (like if the exponent is biased, and whether some exponent values are reserved), so I made certain assumptions. I've added a couple of links in my answer to references that you might find useful. Using a mantissa of only zeroes gives me the value `1 * power(2, exponent-bias)`, so to get `power(2, exponent-bias) == 0.5` we want `exponent-bias`to equal `-1`. Assuming a bias of 63 that gives us `exponent == 62`.